# HTTP 303: http:// instead of http://www results in Loop / 303

Tags: redirect, joomla, joomla-sef-urls

I have a Joomla! 1.5.23 website running [Artio](http://www.artio.net/joomsef/documentation) for SEF urls. 
Complete configuration:

- JoomSEF3 3.9.5
- Virtuemart JoomSEF extension 2.1.1
- Joomla! 1.5.23
- Virtuemart 1.1.9
- Joomfish 2.0.4

I have told Artio (SEF component) to use www urls only. Somehow when I go to a http:// url without the www the browsers hangs. Firefox 11 tell me

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

Telling Artio not to handle the www non-www stuff and purging the urls still gets me the same issue going to a non-www url.
Firebug shows me a status 303 - see other - in both cases (both Artio settings) . Makes me think it is a .htaccess issue or a DNS issue. Here is the .htaccess:

```
##
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 9975 2008-01-30 17:02:11Z ircmaxell $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2008 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
# Joomla! is Free Software
##


#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
# Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

# non-www to www

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]


#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section


########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits


######## Redirect to keep old site running
#
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
#
######## End Redirect preservation

######## Fix memory issue 
php_value memory_limit 40M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

I never had a 303 before. How can I make www-less urls work again?

**Update 1**

When I uncommented

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I  got a 301 and could not reach the site using a www url

**Update 2**
Doing some testing this week together with Artio, the makers of the SEF component. Nobody here seems to have a clue so this seems to be the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good people at [Artio](http://www.artio.net/) found the issue for me: *"... the problem was caused by „Use 302 redirect“ option being enabled in System – Jfrouter plugin. Non-www domain seems to be correctly redirected to www if this option is disabled."* All good now.